# Substring implementation via Span<T>

Tags: c#, c#-7.2, system.memory

How would an implementation of a `SubstringFromStart` method look like when `Span<T>` should be leveraged? Assuming `substringLength <= input.Length`:

```
 ReadOnlySpan<char> span = input.AsSpan().Slice(0, substringLength);
 return new string(span.ToArray());
```

Is this the way to go? Is there a better, more concise way than `new string(span.ToArray())`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this the way to go?

No, using `Span<T>` is useless here, since you need a character array for the string constructor (there is none that accepts a `Span<char>` yet).

You would benefit using `Span<T>` here if:

- You would return the `Span<char>`, rather than a `string`. Then you wouldn't need the string allocation;
- You receive a `Span<char>` as input and you never need to materialize it to an array, or you wouldn't need a intermediate materialization (when passing it into the method for example).